# How to convert NSString to float without rounding it?

Tags: swift, type-conversion

I have tried the following but when I convert the string it is automatically rounded.

```
let str = "10,60"
let str2 = (str as NSString).floatValue //prints "10.0"

//What I would like to do
let str2 = (str as NSSTring).floatValueNotRounded //prints "10,60"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.floatValue` does not handle local formats and your number uses a comma as the decimal point - the the parse just stops at the comma and you get `10`. Use either `NumberFormatter` or `Scanner` to parse localised numbers. E.g.:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
let val = formatter.number(from: str)
```

should work provided your locale uses the comma as the decimal point. If you are in one locale and wish to parse numbers written according to another you can set `locale` property of the formatter.